# Main page on Github?

Tags: git, github, readme

I have 2 questions about GitHub:

1. How can I pin the project to the main page on my GitHub ?
2. If I add `README.md` from my computer to my repo on GitHub, will it be automatically displayed as a `README` or should I create `README` directly on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the [item pinning feature](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/pinning-items-to-your-profile) available at your GitHub profile page:

> You can pin a public repository if you own the repository or you've made contributions to the repository.
> In the "`Popular repositories`" or "`Pinned`" section, click `Customize your pins`.

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/profile/select-items-to-pin.png]

You can create a `README.md` in your local repository, but you will have to add, commit and push it in order to appear as "`README.ld`" in your remote repository.
See an example in my project [`VonC/gtarsum`](https://github.com/VonC/gtarsum).